# Looking for an Alternative Proof of a Bound on the Number of Maximal Ideals in an Integral Extension Lying over a Maximal Ideal in the Base Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, alternative-proof, maximal-and-prime-ideals, integral-extensions

> Consider integral domains $R$ and $T$ such that $R \subseteq T.$ Given an element $a \in T$ that satisfies a monic polynomial of degree $d$ with coefficients in $R,$ consider the subring $S = R[a] = \{r_0 + r_1 a + \cdots + r_{d - 1} a^{d - 1} \,|\, r_i \in R\}$ of $T.$ If $Q$ is a maximal ideal of $R,$ prove that there are $\leq d$ maximal ideals $P \subseteq S$ with $P \cap R = Q.$

One can prove this in the following manner. (Credit is due to [Souvik Dey](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42041/souvik-dey) for the following argument.)

> Consider a maximal ideal $Q$ of $R$ and a prime ideal $P$ of $S$ such that $P \cap R = Q.$ On the level of sets, we have that $Q \subseteq P,$ hence there is a containment of ideals $QS \subseteq PS = P$ of $S.$ We conclude that every prime ideal $P$ of $S$ such that $P \cap R = Q$ contains the ideal $QS,$ hence we may consider the set $\operatorname{Spec}(S / QS) = \{P \,|\, P \text{ is a prime ideal of } S / QS \}.$ We claim that $$\begin{align*} \operatorname{Spec}(S / QS) = \operatorname{MaxSpec}(S / QS) &= \{M \,|\, M \text{ is a maximal ideal of } S / QS \} \text{ and } \\ \\ \lvert \operatorname{Spec}(S / QS) \rvert &\leq d \end{align*}.$$ Considering that $S = R \langle a_0, \dots, a_{d - 1} \rangle$ is an $R$-module and $Q$ annihilates $S / QS,$ it follows that $S / QS$ is an $R/Q$-vector space by hypothesis that $Q$ is a maximal ideal of $R.$ We note that the dimension of $S / QS$ over $R / Q$ is $\leq d$ since it can be generated by the $d$ elements $a_0 + QS, \dots, a_{d - 1} + QS$ over $R,$ hence $S / QS$ is Artinian as a ring. Consequently, $S / QS$ has finitely many prime ideals $P_1, \dots, P_n,$ and they are all maximal, hence we have that $\operatorname{Spec}(S / QS) = \operatorname{MaxSpec}(S / QS).$ Further, we have that $P_i + P_j = S / QS$ so that $P_i^r + P_j^r = S / QS$ for each pair of integers $1 \leq i < j \leq n$ and any positive integer $r.$ By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, it follows that $$\frac{S / QS}{(P_1 \cdots P_n)^r} = \frac{S / QS}{P_1^r \cdots P_n^r} \cong \prod_{i = 1}^n \frac{S / QS}{P_i^r}.$$ Considering that $S / QS$ is Artinian, the nilradical $\operatorname{Rad}(0)$ is nilpotent, i.e., there exists an integer $r \gg 0$ such that $\operatorname{Rad}(0)^r = 0.$ We have therefore that $$0 = \operatorname{Rad}(0)^r = (P_1 \cap \cdots \cap P_n)^r = (P_1 \cdots P_n)^r = P_1^r \cdots P_n^r,$$ from which it follows by our above isomorphism that $$\frac S {QS} \cong \prod_{i = 1}^n \frac{S / QS}{P_i^r}.$$ Each quotient ring $(S / QS) / P_i^r$ is a nonzero $R/Q$-vector space (as each quotient ring is annihilated by $Q$), hence its dimension over $R/Q$ is $\geq 1.$ We have therefore that $$n \leq \sum_{i = 1}^n \dim \frac{S / QS}{P_i^r} = \dim \prod_{i = 1}^n \frac{S / QS}{P_i^r} = \dim \frac S {QS} \leq d,$$ from which it follows that $\lvert \operatorname{Spec}(S / QS) \rvert = \lvert \operatorname{MaxSpec}(S / QS) \rvert = n \leq d,$ as desired.

I am searching for a more elementary proof of the initial fact. If possible, I would like to prove this without relying on the structure of $S$ as an $R$-module or the fact that $S / QS$ is Artinian. Ultimately, I would simply appreciate any thoughts or suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not exactly your question, but very closely related: Exercises 12-15 in Atiyah-Macdonald. This treats general rings but basically under the assumption that the extension is "Galois". For your domains, you can probably drop Galois if the extension of fraction fields is separable by using the Galois closure. Even in the inseparable case you might be able to push it through if you're very careful. These would all give you the more general result that your claim is true for $T$ if it is "finite degree", rather than having to restrict to $R[a]$.

Comment: That is useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different proof, based on the fact that if $A$ is a finite dimensional $k$ algebra for $k$ a field, with $n$ distinct maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}_i$, and $k$ algebra maps $\lambda_i: A\rightarrow A/\mathfrak{m_i}\rightarrow K$ for $K$ a field, then these $\lambda_i$ are $K$ linearly independent. Summarised as "Field homomorphisms are linearly independent".

First lets prove this, consider a linear dependence of homomorphisms, $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \lambda_i(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$, $\alpha_i \in K$. Since the kernel $\mathfrak{m}_i$ of $\lambda_i$ is a maximal ideal, we will be done if we can find some $x$ in $\bigcap_{j\neq i}\mathfrak{m}_j\setminus \mathfrak{m_i}$, since this will force $\alpha_i=0$. For this, take an element $\beta_j$ in each $\mathfrak{m_j}\setminus \mathfrak{m_i}$ (nonempty by maximality), and multiply them together. This element satisfies our condition by construction.

So with this fact, consider now the maximal ideal $Q$ of $R$ inside $R[\alpha]$. Since $\alpha$ had monic minimal polynomial of degree $d$, we have that $R[\alpha]$ is a free $R$ module of rank $d$. So tensoring over $R$ with $R/Q$ yields the algebra $R/Q[\bar{\alpha}]$, which is a $R/Q$ vector space of dimension $d$. Observe that each maximal ideal $P_i$ in $R[\alpha]$ containing $Q$ yields a maximal ideal in this quotient, which yields a finite extension of $R/Q$, and we can find a large enough common field $K$ to recieve an embedding from each of these.

So we are in the situation of the lemma, so since the $K$ vector space $Hom_k(R/Q[\bar{\alpha}],K)$ is at most $d$ dimensional (over $K$), we can have at most $d$ maximal ideals $P_i$ extending $Q$.

Edit:
I realise that this still relies on the structure of $S=R[\alpha]$ as an $R$ module, but this fact, that adjoining a root of a monic polynomial yields a free module of rank=degree is of a lower level (and more fundamental than) the rest of the proof in my opinion.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the statement, "Each maximal ideal $P_i$ in $R[\alpha]$ containing $Q$ [...] yields a finite extension of $R/Q$?"

Comment: So if $P_i$ contains $Q$, then the composite map to the quotient $R\rightarrow R[\alpha]\rightarrow R[\alpha]/P_i$ has $Q$ in its kernel, so gives a morphism $R/Q\rightarrow R[\alpha]/P_i$. This is finite since this vector space is a quotient of the (finite dimensional) $R[\alpha]\otimes_R Q\cong R[\alpha]/Q^e$.

Comment: I don't quite see the isomorphism $R[\alpha] \otimes_R Q \cong R[\alpha] / Q^e.$

Comment: I noticed also that you claim that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree $d.$ Can that be established from the hypotheses?

Comment: The isomorphism can be proven by tensoring the sequence $0\rightarrow Q\rightarrow R\rightarrow R/Q \rightarrow 0$ with $R[\alpha]$, and noting that tensor is right exact, and the image of $Q\otimes_{R}R[\alpha]$ is $Q^e$. You are correct that we can't establish the degree of the minimal polynomial is $d$, it might actually be smaller. I should have said that we may assume its minimal poly is degree $d$, if it isn't, just apply the argument to the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.